# Diagonalization of the differential of a smooth map between two Riemannian manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

I have no idea about the diagonalization of the differential of a smooth map between two Riemannian manifolds. Let $f:N\to M$ be a smooth map between two Riemannian manifolds $(N,\bar{g})$ and $(M,g)$ with dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively.

My question is that why we can choose a local $\bar{g}$-orthonormal frame $\bar{e}_1,\cdots,\bar{e}_n$ of $TN$ and a local $g$-orthonormal frame $e_1,\cdots,e_m$ of $TM$ such that

$$f_*\bar{e}_i=\begin{cases}
\mu_i e_i,\quad \text{if}\ i\leq\min(m,n)\\
0,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
with $\mu_i\geq 0$.

I'm not sure if the question is too easy. Could you give me some help with the details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the requirement is to be satisfied in a single point (i.e. not in a neighborhood), then you're asking precisely for SVD decomposition: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: Can any linear transformation between two Euclidean spaces have an SVD decomposition? Of course, here Euclidean spaces are tangent spaces of $N$ and $M$ respectively. Does it need other additional conditions?@lisyarus